# How do I know which requirements my server needs for my database?

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, digital-ocean

I need to reduce the cost of servers.
the current server has the application
web, the database. the technical characteristics in general are

- 5tb
- 16 cpus
- 30gb ram

the current application does not exceed 100 users per day, the database weighs approx 30 GB. for these reasons the current server expense seems too much to me. I checked in digital ocean droplet and proposed to have the web application in an 8 CPUs, 16 GB ram, 1tb. the database in a 4 CPUs, 16 GB ram, 240 GB solid disk. But how can I know if what I am proposing is correct? to make the server change. thanks for your help.

Comment: You can't tell until you run some tests. What are these 100 users per day doing? Are they logging in to do 1 transaction or do each user perform hundreds of transactions each? Are they reading/writing a couple GB from 3-4 tables or 40-50 GB across several tables? If you know how the database and application is used, you can replicate them on a cheap digital ocean server and use Apache JMeter to simulate traffic and see how the server holds up.

Comment: They will make approximately 50 transactions or less, each will use a maximum of 10 tables, per day it will be less than 1gb,I have not used Apache JMeter, but I will find out how to use it, thanks for the answer

Comment: Try the $20/mo. droplet that gives you 4G RAM, 2 vCPU and 80G SSD on DigitalOcean. Set up your app/db. and see if it operates reasonably. If it does not, you can scale up without downtime to a $40/mo. droplet of double the size. 5,000 transactions a day shouldn't be that hard to pull off on a reasonably priced server.

Answer (score 2):

Nobody can tell you the size of equipment you would use because this is **totally dependent upon your application and how it is used**.

For example, some applications are **CPU-heavy** (doing video processing), some require a lot of **memory** (keeping lots of data accessible), some are **disk-dependent** (doing database transactions). The "shape" of every application is different. Your application might be able to take advantage of multiple CPUs, or perhaps it is only using some of them.

Also, **how users interact** with every application is different. People use Facebook different to a banking app, different to a gaming website. If your 100 users are all in the same timezone, then usage will be different to having them spread around the world.

The only way to know what specification is require is either to **monitor live traffic on the website** and observe how CPU, RAM and disk is used, or **simulate levels of traffic** to reproduce what users typically do on the website and then measure the behaviour of the system.

Then there is the question of **reliability**. Consider whether you willing to run everything on one server, where the app might be unavailable if something goes wrong. Or perhaps you need **high availability** to ensure uptime, but at a greater cost.

Since you appear to be cost-conscious, I would recommend:

- **Monitor** your current system (CPU, RAM, network, disk) during periods of normal usage.
- If some aspects seem **over-provisioned**, then reduce them (eg if CPU never goes above 40%, reduce it). Check whether all CPUs are being used.
- Use some form of **continual monitoring** to notify you when the application is not behaving as desired.
- Keep **log files** to allow you to deep-dive into what might be causing the application problems.